# converting string to datetime object in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, datetime

I'm trying to convert a string into a datetime object...

```
time = '10:00:00'
date = '2016-10-03'
date = date + ' ' + time
print date
date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%y')
print date
```

this prints out:

```
2016-10-03 10:00:00
2000-10-03 10:00:00
```

for some reason it changes the year date..

when I do:

```
date = '2016-10-03'
date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
print date
```

It works correct and I get:

```
2016-10-03
```

How come when I add the time in there it changes the year?

Thanks

Comment: The %y at the end should be a %S --> seconds not year in the time. @McGrady beat me to it! Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
time = '10:00:00'                                       
date = '2016-10-03'                                     
date = date + ' ' + time                                
print date                                              
print datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

> %y    Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.
>   %Y    Year with century as a decimal number.

It seems that you just made a misspelling.Maybe what you want is `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`.

See more details from [datetime Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).Hope this helps.

Comment: @nrs90 if this was the answer can you please accept it? gives the answerer more rep and then this question is marked as solved